# SPListItem not added to SPList

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, splistitem

I'm using the following code to add an item to a list on the top level of my application but it is not adding anything, does anyone know why? Is there anything missing?

It doesn't return me any error, just doesn't add the item and the list remains empty.

The code is in the FeatureActivated method of the feature where the list instance is being deployed.

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList icons = web.GetList(path)

                  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                  {
                    SPListItem icon = icons.Items.Add();

                    icon[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = "title";
                    icon[new Guid("d3429cc9-adc4-439b-84a8-5679070f84cb")] = "class1";

                    icons.Update();
                  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to call the Update() method of the **icon** object, not icons.

Comment: that's it! I thought the list had to be updated but it's the item. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome :-) you only update the list object if you make changes to the list itself. icons.Items.Add() doesn't actually add an item to the Items collection, it only returns an item (with all fields that exist in the lists)

Answer (score 0):

I found out there are 2 ways of successfully add an item to a list:

1. Like Andreas Scharf said:

```
SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
item["Title"] = "some title";
item.Update();
```

1. Some other way using the AddItem() instead of the Add() from the items collection

```
SPListItem item = list.AddItem();
item["Title"] = "some title"; // Add item's field values
item.Update(); //also the item is updated, not the list
```